# Show complete text of options in ObjectChoiceField in BlackBerry?

Tags: blackberry, choicefield

[image]

In my application I am using **ObjectChoiceField**. Some options in the list are very lengthy and when I opens up the list of Choice field I can't see the complete text of the option in the list.
Also I am using the style as **ForceSingleLine** so that after selecting any option the ObjectChoiceField must not get double in height. I know that its the problem with the list.

So please suggest me, how can i show complete text in the list of any option in OCF in blackbery.

Comment: Text is showing according to the width of the screen; then you should decrease the text size; I think it is difficult to find the solution;

Comment: Ohk...:( I thought if its possible to control the width of the row of my drop down lost.
Anyways thanx alot for your suggestion.